# How to get data from HTTPS response using Haskell?

Tags: http, haskell, https, client

I use this line of Haskell code to read the content of an HTTP response:

`simpleHTTP (getRequest addr) >>= getResponseBody`

This line works very well for domains like http://www.example.com, but if I try something like https://www.example.com, I get an error saying that HTTPS is not supported.

How can I make the code snippet work for HTTPS?

Thank you in advance :)

PS: I don't want to install additional libraries

Comment: You won't be able to do this without additional libraries unless you re-implement [`http-client`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html) which is the standard method. The `httpLbs` in `http-conduit` uses this.

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy with the http-conduit package. For example:

```
bash> stack --resolver lts-6.7 repl http-conduit
ghci> :set -XOverloadedStrings 
ghci> import qualified Network.HTTP.Simple as H
ghci> H.getResponseBody <$> H.httpLBS "https://google.com"
```

https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-6.7/http-conduit-2.1.11/Network-HTTP-Simple.html#v:httpLBS

Comment: yes, but I don't want to install additional packages.

Comment: Is there a way to do that just using haskell-platform?

Comment: There may be, but I've never bothered doing it that way. The documentation for `Network.HTTP` says that "This package only supports HTTP; it does not support HTTPS. Attempts to use HTTPS result in an error." However, I think this may be outdated and it may be possible to use the stuff provided in `Network.TCP` (from the same package).